# Is foreign music a good reason to learn a language?

Tags: motivation

I learned German while I was into NDH metal. Its the only language I learned well at all. But I stopped studying the language after I found out that I knew and understood German words that I didn't know the English translation to (I was afraid I was forgetting English). Then I lost interest in NDH some time after that and never picked it up again. I still understand it, though I struggle to form sentences of my own now.

I've thought about picking up language again, but I'm not so sure about using foreign music as a motivator for learning a language anymore. For one, it can give you a false impression of the language. Also, it doesn't involve you actually producing sentences of your own. I've tried to look for places where I could talk in various target languages I want, but none of them seem to be too active (it seems like nobody uses forums anymore).

I'm struggling to find a way to immerse myself in a language. I just can't seem to find any. I can't find anyway to actually use any language I learn, and the only things I can think of where I'll get any exposure to a language is music, and perhaps reading foreign news.

Comment: Do you want a response to the title, or do you want help with finding ways to immerse yourself (in German or some other language)?

Comment: The title. It would be better for people who are looking to learn any language, not just German. I just mentioned my own experiences learning that way. One thing that is apparent: it doesn't help you learn to USE the language, plus you may lose interest in the language if you lose interest in the music.

Answer (score 4):

To me its quite obvious that **anything that motivates you is good for learning** a language.

If you strictly mean "*should I learn a language because I like music that is in that language*", then I think this is a call you need to make for yourself.

Learning, "just" via listening to music and translations of it, as you point out, has obvious shortcomings of course. But I think, as I said, using it as something that drives you and keeps you interested is a great thing, if the language and music you're interested in fit together :D !

---

*Addition*: you say you find no way to put the language you've learned to use - one way would to be engage with the online community that commonly exists around famous bands. In this case, I would think they'd typically communicate in German :) . Unless you're actually going to Germany for a concert, this does limit you to written language though...

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, subcultures are not very good to motivate with.

You are safe if you don't believe in stereotypes about the culture itself (like German for example, I mean you could dig up some WW2 topics that may appear rather controversial).

Ever heard of ***weeaboos*** or ***weebs***? People outside Japan having interests in cool Japanese tricks, Anime, music and other stuff that teenagers (probably in their rooms gaming instead) are luring themself into.

I think that you need to be dedicated to the history and culture as well. For example, do you know anything about Germany itself? Is it actually a sign of being respectful if you put one or two fingers up (an inappropriate gesture where I live)? Do they practice Buddhism? Do they wear jeans or woolly trousers?  If music was a motivator, then almost everyone would be learning Spanish after listening to Despacito (unfortunately, it does happen out there).

After listening to 2NE1, do we learn Korean?
After listening to PonPonPon, Japanese?
After listening to Despacito? Spanish?
After eating their food, Chinese?
After eating Indian curries, Hindi? Exactly, right!

In a nutshell, learn German because you've fallen in love with it, not because of a boring Weekend.

Comment: Thank you for the +1 upvote, guys. <3 this is what kind of advice I actually believe in. After all, languages should be learned as a hobby (but still, please learn some culture) or just interests in culture.